# How safe is the Hampi Express, to have a night ride from Hampi to Bangalore?

Tags: trains, india, bangalore

How safe is the Hampi Express, to have a night ride from Hampi to Bangalore?

I'm a solo traveler (man).
Is this train safe in terms of theft? Can I sleep during the trip?

Comment: It is probably pretty safe if you use the air conditioned classes. If you are not from India, the usual precautions of train travel in India applies. [Seat61](https://www.seat61.com/India.htm) and [LonelyPlanet](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/india/transport/getting-around/train) have excellent guides on train travel in India. The seat61 pieces on advance reservation may be a bit outdated though and it is likely there are more options than those mentioned.